# Sencha Touch 2:

Tags: extjs, cursor, focus, sencha-touch-2, messagebox

I'm getting
    **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of undefined**
happens when

```
Ext.Msg.prompt with #myinput closed and then opened **again**.
Ext.getCmp('myinput').focus(); works fine for the first time only. How to set the cursor into `myinput` always?
```

It works for the first time message box opened only.

Update: below is my core code.

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('',
    'Some text description', 
    function(btn, text) {

    },
    this,
    false,
    null,
    { placeHolder: 'Please enter some text here', xtype: 'numberfield', id: 'myinput' }
);
Ext.getCmp('myinput').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that `Ext.getCmp('myinput')` doesn't find your field. So maybe the field is not created yet at the time you call the function, or maybe you've got a type in the id, or probably, given your description, that the second time you call it the field has been destroyed... Impossible to say for sure without the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a component query.

Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#myinput").focus();